# Atualizar Arquivos no BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Eu tenho uma dúvida sobre como atualizar meus arquivos no bitbucket, o repositório já foi criado e já fiz o 1 commit.
Então se precisar subir novos arquivos eu preciso clonar o repositório e colocar os novos arquivos nessa pasta e depois subir novamente?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de já ter instalado o [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads), pra propor mudanças no seu repositório podes usar o `add`. Veja:

```
git add <arquivo> # podes mandar um único arquivo pelo nome
git add .         # podes mandar todos arquivos alterados
```

Para realmente confirmar estas mudanças (isto é, fazer um commit), use:

```
git commit -m "comentários das alterações"
```

Suas alterações agora estão no `HEAD` da sua cópia de trabalho local. Para enviar estas alterações ao seu repositório remoto, execute:

```
git push origin master
```

Par amais detalhes, leia esse [guia prático](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html).